# How to convert mpeg-dash files back to mp4 or mkv via FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video, video-encoding

Recently I tried downloading a video file via a program called "video cache view", it created two video files instead of one numbered as mpegdashtmp1.mp4 which are i guess in some mpeg-dash format. I searched about it and came to know that out of these two files one should contain the audio and the other will be the video part. How can I convert those files to mp4/mkv via FFMPEG.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your research is right, use

```
ffmpeg -i mpegdashtmp1.mp4 -i mpegdashtmp2.mp4 -c copy -absf aac_adtstoasc single.mp4
```